# Getting Assembly manifest error while trying to build Wix msi project after referencing CA dll

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I have a simple project and a wix msi which is building fine. Now I needed to implement Custom Action and created a Custom Action project which is building fine.

However when I try to build the Wix project after referencing the CA dll it is throwing the following error.

> '..\WixCustomAction\bin\Debug\WixCustomAction.CA.dll' could not be loaded because of the following reason: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Repos\Clients\WixCustomAction\bin\Debug\WixCustomAction.CA.dll' or one of its dependencies.